# Code inside block is wrapped inside parens. Why?

Tags: javascript

I came across this code and don't understand why the code within the block is wrapped in the parens like an auto-executing function.

```
function foo(a,b) {
  var b = b || window,
    a = a.replace(/^\s*<!(?:\[CDATA\[|\-\-)/, "/*$0*/"); 
  if (a && /\S/.test(a)) {
    (b.execScript || function (a) {
      b["eval"].call(b, a)
    })(a);
  }
}
```

The first parameter is the text from a script tag. The only part I don't get is why the script eval is wrapped in parens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are talking about this part:

```
(b.execScript || function (a) {
    b["eval"].call(b, a)
})(a);
```

This is short form of writing:

```
if (b.execScript) {
    b.execScript(a);
}
else {
    b["eval"].call(b, a);
}
```

I.e. execute `b.execScript` if it is defined, otherwise call `b["eval"].call(b, a)`.

The purpose of the grouping operator is to evaluate `... || ...` before the function call, i.e. whatever the result of the grouping operator is, it is treated as function and called by passing `a` to it.

It looks like the code could be simplified to

```
(b.execScript || b["eval"])(a);
```

Though if explicitly setting `this` to `b` is necessary, then the function expression is necessary as well, to have two functions that only accept one argument, `a`.

Comment: ... unless there is no need to call `eval` in the context of non-window `b`.

Comment: Maybe, I haven't actually looked at what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: In somehow looks like [`globalEval`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/core.js#L587) from jQuery < master, while this code should evaluate the script from string representation (possibly after Ajax call).

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense, i just hadn't ever seen this construct before.

Answer (score 4):

```
(b.execScript || function (a) {
      b["eval"].call(b, a)
    })(a)
```

This is wrapped in parens because the `||` statement needs to be evaluated to determine what function to run before being passed an argument.

This code calls `b.execScript` with argument `a` if `b.execScript` exists and is truthy.  Otherwise it defines a new function and passes `a` as an argument to that.

The parens wrap is to make sure that the `||` statement is evaluated before the function is executed.  Without it the logic would go basically, if b.exec doesn't exist, evaluate to the value of the custom function, if it does, evaluate to b.exec.

So with the parens the logic is equivalent to:

```
if(b.execScript){
   b.execScript(a)
}
else{
  function (a) {
    b["eval"].call(b, a)
  })(a)

}
```

without it, its equivalent to

if(!b.execScript){
   function (a) {
        b["eval"].call(b, a)
      })(a)
}

Answer (score 3):

It's parenthesized because the `||` operator binds more loosely than the function invocation operator `()`.  Without the enclosing parentheses, the expression would be evaluated as if it were written:

```
b.execScript || (function (a) { b["eval"].call(b, a); })(a)
```

That is, it'd be either the plain value of `b.execScript` or the value of invoking that function.  What the author wanted was invoke either the value of `b.execScript` (which would presumably be a function) *or* that little anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the `(a)` afterwards.  The expression:

```
(b.execScript || function (a) {
      b["eval"].call(b, a)
    })
```

returns a closure which is then executed with `a` passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The parenthetical expression returns either the result of b.execScript, or a new function.  In either case, the result is then invoked with a as a parameter.  The parens make sure the interpreter evaluates the || before the invocation.

Answer (score 0):

> why the code within the block is wrapped in the parens like an auto-executing function.

Because that particular part of the code *is* an auto-executing function:

```
(b.execScript || function (a) {
    b["eval"].call(b, a)
})(a);
```

Here, the variable `b` references the execution container, e.g. `window`, and `a` contains JavaScript code that needs to be executed.

Since some browsers support `execScript()` while some only support `eval()`, the code supports them both by testing this browser feature like so:

```
var tmp = b.execScript || function (a) {
  b["eval"].call(b, a)
};
```

Here, `tmp` is a function that takes a single parameter `a` and executes the code within; if `execScript` is not available, a small helper function is used instead. And then it's called like this:

```
tmp.call(b, a);
```

The first parameter to `.call()` defines what `this` refers to when `tmp` is called; the second parameter becomes the first parameter of `tmp`.